# How to unselect checkboxes after bulk action execution?

Tags: datagrid, react-admin

On a `List` module, I created a bulk action button to generate PDF by calling a custom action.
The problem is `<Datagrid>` checkboxes are not unselected once the action is executed.

Here is my custom action:

```
export const print = (resource, ids, data) => ({
  type: DOWNLOAD,
  payload: {
    id: ids.length === 1 ? ids[0] : ids,
    data,
  },
  meta: {
    resource: resource,
    fetch: PRINT,
    onFailure: {
      notification: {
        body: 'ra.notification.http_error',
        level: 'warning',
      },
    },
  },
});
```

And here is my button:

```
class PrintBulkButton extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    const { basePath, options, print, resource, selectedIds } = this.props;

    print(resource, selectedIds, options, basePath);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Button {...sanitizeRestProps(this.props)} onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.props.icon}
      </Button>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm using react-admin 2.3.0, but it wasn't working with previous versions either.

I think the checkboxes are not unchecked because the service I call doesn't update data.
Am I right?

Do I have to call another service or action to uncheck them, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this `onSuccess` side effect parameter `unselectAll: true` that we should document (please open an issue for it):

```
export const print = (resource, ids, data) => ({
  type: DOWNLOAD,
  payload: {
    id: ids.length === 1 ? ids[0] : ids,
    data,
  },
  meta: {
    resource: resource,
    fetch: PRINT,
    onSuccess: {
        unselectAll: true,
    },
    onFailure: {
      notification: {
        body: 'ra.notification.http_error',
        level: 'warning',
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I took a look in the source code to see how it works and I saw it's already documented: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Actions.html#handling-side-effects. A little bit hidden but it's there!