# React admin: clear selectedIds after some action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-admin

So I have a component like so:

```
...
import dataProvider from 'myCustomDataProvider';

class Something extends React.Component {
  somethingBulk(selectedIds) {
    await dataProvider(SOMETHING, 'something', {
      data: { selectedIds },
    })
    this.props.refreshView();
  }

  render() {
    const props = this.props;

    return (
      <List 
        {...props} 
        bulkActions={<BulkActionsBar onConfirm={this.somethingBulk} />}
        filters={null} 
        exporter={false}
      >
        <Datagrid>...</Datagrid>
      </List>
    );
  }
}

export default compose(
  connect(
    null,
    {
      showNotification,
      refreshView,
      fetchStart,
      fetchEnd,
    }
  ),
)(Something);
```

`BulkActionsBar` is a simple component with a button that onClick calls `somethingBulk`.
Now, the line `this.props.refreshView()` refreshes the list, fetches new records and everything is fine. Except that the checkboxes remain checked, selectedIds is retaining its value.

So the question, what's the proper way to clear that list? I understand I have to dispatch some redux action but I couldnt find an example anywhere.

Comment: About the examples you haven't found, the official Redux website explains very well some techniques you can use to [dispatch actions from connected React components using react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch). I suggest you to take a look.

Comment: Did you connected component `Something` to store? Please provide how did you connected it. When state is changed, `props` get updated automatically and component re-renders with new values. So it may be issue with your connect function

Comment: Here is a similar question: "How to unselect checkboxes after bulk action execution?" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52280137/how-to-unselect-checkboxes-after-bulk-action-execution

Comment: @RPichioli the thing is, what's the action I have to dispatch to clear the list. That's whats not documented in react-admin.

Comment: @Fyodor I updated my question, you can see how I connected. If I remember right, I stole that from the docs of react-admin somewhere. As I have read, they unselect the list when you perform some crud action, but since my action is custom it doesnt do it.

Comment: @MaxAlex I saw that but discarted it...might be something, will have a second look. Thanks

Comment: @yBrodsky, it's good to see full working sample for example on https://codesandbox.io. From provided code I see, that you've not mapped redux state to props (you've passed `null` as first argument to `connect()`). So you should get `props` from parent. But the same time you've mapped `dispatch` to `props` so you dispatch actions directly. Such approach is not widely used.and may lead to errors

Answer (score 1):

this is an old question, but as i ran into this issue too, just to let future visitors know that there is now (react admin 4+) a hook for this:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/useUnselect.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments and on the information provided in this other question: [How to unselect checkboxes after bulk action execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52280137/how-to-unselect-checkboxes-after-bulk-action-execution) I was able to make it work.

```
import { withDataProvider } from 'react-admin';

class Something extends React.Component {
  somethingBulk(selectedIds) {
    const { dataProvider } = this.props;
    await dataProvider(SOMETHING, 'something', {
      data: { selectedIds },
    }, {
      onSuccess: {
        refresh: true,
        unselectAll: true,
      },
      onFailure: {
        unselectAll: true,
        notification: { level: 'warning' },
      },
    });

  }

  render() {
    const props = this.props;

    return (
      <List 
        {...props} 
        bulkActions={<BulkActionsBar onConfirm={this.somethingBulk} />}
        filters={null} 
        exporter={false}
      >
        <Datagrid>...</Datagrid>
      </List>
    );
  }
}

export default withDataProvider(Something);
```

Make sure you are using the latest version of react-admin, I was using an older version which didnt export `withDataProvider`. So you can pass a 4th param to the data provider which handles side effects.